# unidentified crash reading json?

Tags: android, json

My app crashes and i cant understand why. The problem seems to appear in the json reader block. It was working since i modified something that i cant remember. Please help me to retrieve the error.

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTaskComplete {

    LinearLayout wrapper = null;
    Context context = this;

    public Bitmap imageHandler;

    @Override
    public void callBackFunction(Bitmap image) {

        imageHandler = image;

    }

    public class Post{

        String id;
        String title;
        String description;
        String release;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public String getRelease() {
            return release;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public void setRelease(String release) {
            this.release = release;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getId() {

            return id;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        //OUTER
        RelativeLayout outer = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.outer);

        //SCROLLER
        Scroller scroller = new Scroller(this);
        scroller.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        //WRAPPER
        wrapper = new LinearLayout(this);
        wrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        outer.addView(scroller);
        scroller.addView(wrapper);


        String result = null;
        ArrayList<Post> focusOn = new ArrayList<Post>();


        try {
            URL address = new URL("http://www.youth-stories.com/api/all.php");
            URLDataReader reader = new URLDataReader(context);
            result = reader.execute(address).get();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
            String success = (String) obj.getString("success");
            JSONArray records = obj.getJSONArray("records");

            for(int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++) {
                Post tmp = new Post();
                tmp.setId(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                tmp.setTitle(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                tmp.setDescription(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("contents"));
                tmp.setRelease(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("data_post"));
                focusOn.add(tmp);
            }

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //wrapper
        LinearLayout container = wrapper;

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("loading contents, please wait..");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        for(int i = 0; i < focusOn.size(); i++) {
            //item
            LinearLayout item = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            String select = focusOn.get(i).getId();
            item.setId(new Integer(select));
            item.setClickable(true);

            //setUp new activity
            final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeOnSelect.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            int id = item.getId();
            String strid = new Integer(id).toString();
            bundle.putString("id",  strid);
            bundle.putString("title",   focusOn.get(i).getTitle());
            bundle.putString("contents", focusOn.get(i).getDescription());
            bundle.putString("release", focusOn.get(i).getRelease());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);

            item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            container.addView(item);
            item.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            item.setPadding(0, 40, 0, 40);
            item.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.postlayout);

            //image
            ImageView asset = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            URL address = null;

            try {

                address = new URL("http://www.youth-stories.com/public/admin/CH_FocusOn/images/" + focusOn.get(i).getId() + "_thumb2.jpg");
                URLImageReader reader = new URLImageReader(this, this, asset, dialog, i, focusOn.size());
                reader.execute(address);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            item.addView(asset);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgSettings = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);

            asset.setLayoutParams(imgSettings);
            asset.setPadding(50,0,0,0);

            //inside
            LinearLayout contents = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            contents.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            contents.setPadding(55, 0, 100, 0);
            item.addView(contents);
            //title
            TextView title = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            title.setText(focusOn.get(i).getTitle());
            title.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.title);
            contents.addView(title);
            //description
            TextView description = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            description.setText(focusOn.get(i).getDescription());
            description.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.description);
            contents.addView(description);
            //date
            TextView date = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            date.setText(focusOn.get(i).getRelease());
            date.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.description);
            contents.addView(date);
            //div
            LinearLayout div = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            div.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 40));
            div.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
            container.addView(div);
        }
    }

}
```

Crash log

```
03-05 12:23:03.276  25591-25591/youth_stories.com.youth_stories E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: youth_stories.com.youth_stories, PID: 25591
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{youth_stories.com.youth_stories/youth_stories.com.youth_stories.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
            at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
            at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
            at youth_stories.com.youth_stories.Home.onCreate(Home.java:129)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: It's a weird error. I think the problem is in your JSON, the values for the contents key of the response seems to be URL encoded. My best bet is that this is somehow causing issues in the JSON parser. Can you change the api? If not try running URLDecoder.decode(result, "UTF-8") before parsing the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

What is in line 129 of your java file?
It must be because you are trying to toString a JSON object which does not exist. You might want to see where the object is being lost.